# How to merge and update pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I'm sorry if this has been asked before but I wasn't sure how to word this question into a search.

I have 2 data frames with a year column and value column. I want to udpate the first data frame based on matching the year and update the value column according to which value is larger. Suppose the data frames look like this

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> x = [1999, 2000, 2001]
>>> y = [0, 0, 0]
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame({'year': x, 'value': y})
>>> df1

   year   value
0  1999   0
1  2000   0
2  2001   0

>>> x2 = [1999, 2003, 2004]
>>> y2 = [5, 0, 0]
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame({'year': x2, 'value': y2})
>>> df2

   year   value
0  1999   5
1  2003   0
2  2004   0
```

I want the updated data frame (`df1`) to look this. Is there a simple way to do this?

```
   year   value
0  1999   5
1  2000   0
2  2001   0
```

Comment: `df1.value = df2.value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df = df1.merge(df2, on=['year'], how='outer')
df['max'] = df.filter(like='value').max(1)
df1['value'] = df1['year'].map(df.set_index('year')['max'])

print(df1)
   year  value
0  1999    5.0
1  2000    0.0
2  2001    0.0
```

**EDIT :** To know which rows are changed use:

```
#intialize the `value` column to `temp` column
df1['temp'] = df1['value']
#now use the above code to change the `value` column
#check which rows are changed with respect to `temp` column
df1['Changed_Values'] = df1['temp'].ne(df1['value'])
#finally drop temporary column
df1.drop('temp', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Hi, I have another question that maybe you can answer. Is there a way to check which values were updated? In other words, I want the same data frame to return but I want for it to print a 'True' where the values were updated.

Comment: @Jack Yes, by temporarily creating a new column for `value` and after changing the values, check which ones are different.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do:

```
if df1.value.sum()<df2.value.sum():
    df1.value = df2.value
```

Or:

```
if df1['value'].sum()<df2['value'].sum():
    df1['value'] = df2['value']
```

Now:

```
print(df1)
```

Is:

```
   year  value
0  1999      5
1  2000      0
2  2001      0
```

Comment: The issue with this is that I want it to only update if the df2['value'] is larger than the df1['value']

Comment: Hi, thanks for the responses. I genuinely appreciate your help but I think I see another issue with your updated response.

With regards to your 2 suggestions, I'm not looking to update based on the sum of column but rather the value at each row of the column.